# Erlang - Standard location of mnesia database

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Is there a standard place to put the mnesia database within erlang? At the moment I am putting it in the priv directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Mnesia will create the schema in a subdirectory called `Mnesia.<node name>` of the current directory of the emulator process.
If that's not what you want, all you need to do is set Mnesia's `dir` application variable with something like

```
application:set_env(mnesia, dir, "/path/to/db").
```

As for where to place the database: that depends on your deployment scenario. Since application
variables can also be set using [release config files](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html) or [command line arguments](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap2.html#id2266729), you can delay that
decision until you ship (or install on your own servers). For use in production, a standard directory like `/var/lib/<your application>/mnesia-<node name>`(on unix) should do.

For playing around, i'd recommend using a dedicated directory under the code root (NOT the priv directory) and setting that location within your application's startup section.
In my pet projects, i often use code such as

```
Root = filename:absname_join(filename:dirname(?FILE), ".."),
application:set_env(mnesia, dir, filename:join(Root, "db")).
```

for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you create the schema every node creates a schema directory in its **root directory**.

Therefore, I guess that can be considered the default location.

If, for some reason, you have to include a schema together with your application, well, I guess the *priv* folder should be fine, since [it is supposed to be used for application specific files](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id2270848) and it's easily accessible via the `code:priv_dir/1` function.